# Google apps script that takes rows from my main spreadsheet, and then creates a new spredsheet for each row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out a Google Script that, given my spreadsheet (with around 300 cells), it scans through all of them, and creates a new individual spreadsheet per row.

I've been searching a lot, but haven´t found some script related to this, so I'm at lost on where to start.

Anybody has something similar, or can give me a hand on where to look to do this?

Comment: Try google `gas copy row` and `gas create sheet` etc.

Comment: The logic would be to read every cell and call the [create() function of Spreadsheetapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)). There's plenty of examples here how to read data from a Google Spreadsheet but [here's another example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to get all your 300 rows of data into your code.

   ```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name of sheet with your data")
   var items = sheet.getRange("A:Z").getValues()
   //items is a 2dim array with all your values
   ```
2. Create new sheet per row

   ```
   var counter = 1
   items.forEach(function(item) {
       ss.insertSheet("Sheet No. " + counter).getRange("A:Z").setValue(item)
       counter++
   })
   ```

Hope this helps - let me know :-)

Comment: probably want counter++

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will look into this too.